# How can I check whether Live Ubuntu 12.04 LTS CD is having defects or not?

Tags: iso, cd

When I burned ubuntu 12.04 LTS CD, I didn't check md5sum of iso file before it. 
I checked option check for defects and it ran perfectly. I doubt that Iso may be corrupted(Viruses,unofficial moded software etc). 
How can I check  whether Live Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  CD is having defects or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Boot the ubuntu live-disk and click on **Try Ubuntu** option.Now you can check for errors without installing ubuntu on your hard-disk.

To check the md5sum of the downloaded ubuntu.iso file refer [*this*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM).

Comment: No k.k. patel is edited my post. How to check if this live cd have viruses ... If a md5sum is answer than how to check md5 without iso and without name of iso file!?

Comment: what's your actual question is?

Comment: If your iso contents viruses , your files in iso would be corrupted and you will get missing files error while checking iso for defects.

Comment: Patel thanks, thanks guys, next time edit and tell why you edit it! And do not erase my info... I was write it all again becouse you delete a lot of post...

Comment: @user223942 you can edit your http://askubuntu.com/posts/388600/edit own question.

Comment: @K.KPatel If your iso contents viruses , your files in iso would be corrupted and you will get missing files error while checking iso for defects. – K.K Patel Dec 10 '13 at 7:29-------------  Have you any source for what you sayin or ...

Comment: @AvinashRaj If your iso contents viruses , your files in iso would be corrupted and you will get missing files error while checking iso for defects. – K.K Patel Dec 10 '13 at 7:29    ----------------  Do you agree with k.k.patel

Comment: There was no possibility of viruses on the Ubuntu iso file but there was a possibility of missing files inside iso that's why checking the md5sum of the iso file.

Answer (score 0):

This step can be done via a VM or by doing a restart of your PC.

Press **ESC** or an equivalent to force the PC to boot from the **CD/DVD ROM media drive**.

A **menu** will appear with options like "Try Ubuntu without installing". There should be an option for **check disc for defects**. Select this option to check your media for defects.

If you for some strange reason, do not see the **check disc for defects option**, the select **F6** for **other options**, and see if you can find it there.

Comment: I was try that but dude edited/deleted my post, part of it... Is option " check disk for defects" check only errors or and viruses etc!

Comment: **check disc for defects** only verifies the state of the media, whether its corrupted or faulty. 

A virus is something much more elusive. Though viruses/worms on Linux are less common. You get tools that are specifically build to clean you hard drives while in booting from a media.

Hope that helps?

Comment: If your iso contents viruses , your files in iso would be corrupted and you will get missing files error while checking iso for defects. – K.K Patel Dec 10 '13 at 7:29

Can anyone else agree with this statement above that K.K Patel posted?